# auto suggesstion in drop down List

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a List Of cities name. I am not sure, I will be explain you better but, I have to do that, if the user type "mumb" in the text box then all the cities name containing "mumb" will be display in drop down box. if user type "bangl" then all the city name containg "bangl" will be display in drop down box. If somebady knows how to do that type of coding then please reply me as soon as possible, it will be very helffull for me.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). I think that does just what you want.

Comment: 7 seconds! Damn your fast fingers :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd check out the jQueryUI autocomplete here http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

That will allow you to do what you need.